# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/tokens'

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a very basic Petri net using tikz and I keep getting the error shown in the title. The code I am using is below.

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]

    \tikzstyle{place}=[circle,thick,draw=black!75,minimum size=12mm]
    \tikzstyle{transition}=[rectangle,thick,fill=black,minimum height=10mm,minimum width=2mm,inner ysep=2pt, inner xsep=2pt]

    \begin{scope}
    \node [place,tokens=2,label=left:condition 1] (p1) {};
    \node [place,label=left:condition 2] (p2) [below of=p1] {};
    \node [place,label=left:condition 3] (p3) [below of=p2] {};
    \node [transition,label=right:machine function] (q3) [right of=p2] {}
    edge [pre] node {1} (p1)
    edge [pre] node {2} (p2)
    edge [pre] node {3} (p3);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

The odd thing is that earlier in my document I use the following code below for a different petri net example, which includes the tokens and it works perfectly, but about a page later the above fails. Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]

    \tikzstyle{place}=[circle,thick,draw=black!75,minimum size=12mm]
    \tikzstyle{transition}=[rectangle,thick,fill=black,minimum height=10mm,minimum width=2mm,inner ysep=2pt, inner xsep=2pt]


    \begin{scope}
    \node [place,tokens=1,label=above:$p_1$] (p1) {};
    \node [transition, label=above:$q_1$] (q1) [right of=p1] {}
    edge [pre] (p1);
    \node [place,label=above:$p_2$] (p2) [right of=q1] {}
    edge [pre] (q1);
    \node [transition,label=above:$q_2$] (q2) [below of=q1] {}
    edge [pre] (p1)
    edge [post] (p2);
    \node [place,tokens=3,label=above:$p_3$] (p3) [below of=p2] {}
    edge [pre] (q2);
    \node [transition,label=above:$q_3$] (q3) [below right of=p2] {}
    edge [pre] (p2)
    edge [pre] (p3);
    \node [place,tokens=2,label=above:$p_4$] (p4) [right of=q3] {}
    edge [pre] (q3);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I can typeset the given source without problems wrapping it into a `standalone` document. Does the error persist when moving the `usetikzlibrary` part into your preamble instead of the document body?

Comment: @epR8GaYuh no that fixed it, I didn't realise I could do it that way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.